# Does the order of computations matter when dealing with only linear transformations and elementwise product/division?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose you had a matrix $A$ of dimensionality $m \times n$, a vector $x$ that is $n \times 1$, and a vector $b$ that is $m \times 1$.

Suppose we design a matrix $B$ that has $n$ copies of $b$ stacked next to each other, so that $B$ is $m \times n$.

I am interested in whether the transformation followed by elementwise division $(Ax) \oslash b$ is the same operation as the elementwise division followed by the transformation $(A \oslash B)x$. This seems to hold up when I try random numbers, but I wanted to make sure I am not making a mistake.

Comment: What is $\oslash$? Elementwise division?

Comment: @twosigma yes $\oslash$ is elementwise division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they give the same thing.

To show that $(A \oslash B)x = (Ax) \oslash b$, we will show that the $i$th element of one equals the $i$th element of the other.

Let $*$ denote multiplication or division.

$$((A \oslash B)x)_i = \text{(row $i$ of $(A \oslash B)$)}x = \begin{bmatrix}a_{i1} * b_{i1} & \cdots & a_{in} * b_{in} \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix} \underbrace{=}_{\text{for any $j$, the $ij$th entry of $B$ is just $b_i$}} \begin{bmatrix}a_{i1} * b_i & \cdots & a_{in} * b_i \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix} = (a_{i1} * b_i) x_1 + … + (a_{in} * b_i)x_n.$$

And
$$\left( (Ax) \oslash b \right)_i = (Ax)_i * b_i = \left( \text{(row $i$ of $A$)}x \right) * b_i = \left( \begin{bmatrix}a_{i1} & \cdots & a_{in} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix} \right) * b_i = (a_{i1}x_1 + … + a_{in}x_n) * b_i \underbrace{=}_{\text{division and multiplication are right-distributive}} (a_{i1}x_1)*b_i + … + (a_{in}x_n) * b_i = (a_{i1} * b_i) x_1 + … + (a_{in} * b_i)x_n.$$